# Deleting huge chunks of data from mysql innodb

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration, innodb

I need to delete a huge chunk of my data in my production database, which runs about 100GB in size. If possible, i would like to minimize my downtime.

My selection criteria for deleting is likely to be

> DELETE * FROM POSTING WHERE USER.ID=5 AND UPDATED_AT<100

What is the best way to delete it?

- Build an index?
- Write a sequential script that deletes via paginating through the rows 1000 at a time?

Comment: Did @Warner's answer work for you?  My current employer is trying to prune 250GB * 20 of data held in InnoDB tables and its eating replication alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can minimize almost all downtime by preventing the table from being locked.

Use a `SELECT INSERT` to migrate the data you want to a temporary table.

Rename the tables.

You'll need to consider any `INSERTS` during the time the `SELECT INSERT` was running.

Finally, drop the table that contains the data you don't want.

Be aware that if you do not have `innodb_file_per_table` enabled in your configuration that the disk space allocated will not be freed.

Additionally, special considerations will be necessary for your application and specific situation.

Here's a procedure that I wrote using this method..

```
# Temp table, recreating forty_first_transaction_
#
CREATE TABLE working_table_temp_ LIKE working_table_;

# Increment if there's an auto_increment field.
#
ALTER TABLE working_table_temp_ AUTO_INCREMENT = 15000000;

# Testing inserts and select while this query was running resulted success.
# Verified no active lock.
#
INSERT INTO working_table_temp_ SELECT * FROM working_table_ WHERE id > $NUM;

RENAME TABLE working_table_ TO working_table_old_;
RENAME TABLE working_table_temp_ TO working_table_;

# Verify that all rows were caught
#
# The last row < 15000000 in both tables should be identical.
#
SELECT * FROM working_table_ where id < 15000000 order by id desc limit 5;
SELECT * FROM working_table_old_ where id < 15000000 order by id desc limit 5;

# If not, we need to move them !
#
# This query will need to be modified.
#
INSERT INTO working_table_ SELECT * FROM working_table_old_ WHERE id > 138376577;

# Verify application functionality, if necessary.
#
# LAST CHANCE FOR BACKOUT !!!
#
# Once verified, get rid of the old data to free up some space.
#
DROP TABLE working_table_old_;
^D

df -h




## BACKOUT ##

RENAME TABLE working_table_ TO working_table_new_;
RENAME TABLE working_table_old_ TO working_table_;
```

Comment: Any idea how to fix the tables with foreign keys that points to the old table?