# Why ibdata1 is still growing when I have used innodb_file_per_table in MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, innodb

All my table in the db are created after I enabled the option "innodb_file_per_table", so I don't understand why ibdata1 is still growing from time to time, even with a very slow speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the complete solution for how to clean up your innodb infrastructure permanently !!!

[I actually solved this question long ago and had this accepted in StackOverflow. Please read this in its entirety, because I performed these steps for my company's clients dozens of times without incident. This will also keep ibdata1 as dirt small as possible. I guarantee it !!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)

[I also addressed this in a question in ServerFault.](https://serverfault.com/questions/230551/mysql-innodb-innodb-file-per-table-cons/231400#231400)

Answer (score 2):

When you use file_per_table, it doesn't mean that ibdata* isn't used at all. There will still be stored "meta-data" for all your InnoDB tables ... Only the data itself goes to the other files