# fine tuning of my.cnf for InnoDB tables fails with setting of: `innodb_log_file_size=256`

Tags: mysql, innodb, tuning

I read some fine tuning recommendations on the [mysqlperfomanceblog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/) and tryed to adapt them.

I added to my.cnf:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 1000M
innodb_log_file_size           = 256M
```

After doing this and restarting the server, I there is no *InnoDB* entry  in the list which the command `SHOW ENGINES` creates in the mysql shell (terminal). If I do comment out the second variable (`innodb_log_file_size`) *InnoDB* is again in the list. What does that mean? [I have read](https://serverfault.com/questions/230551/mysql-innodb-innodb-file-per-table-cons/231400#231400) that `innodb_log_file_size` should be 1/4 times of the size of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the old innodb log files which aren't the right size anymore.

Comment: Where do I find those old innodb log files?

Comment: @Aufwind, Usually /var/lib/mysql. Check your my.cnf to see what your datadir is pointing to. Make sure that your server shuts down properly - check your MySQL's [log-]error log.

Comment: If you cannot locate the log files, you should run 'updatedb' and then run 'locate ib_logfile0'. This tells you where the log file is located. There will be 2 logfiles : ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1.