# Unknown table engine 'InnoDB' after deleting ibdata1 file

Tags: mysql, innodb

I was having innodb with one ibdata file. i have changed it in my.cnf to have ibd file for every table (innodb_file_per_table). then i run the following query on all of my innodb tables to have its own ibd file

```
alter table tablename engine=innodb;
```

now after converting all of my tables, ibdata still having the same size, so i have deleted it, and restarted mysql. mysql has created it again with 10MB size (as defined in my.cnf)
but the problem now is that i can see all of my tables normally when  **show tables;**
but whenever i want to **desc tablename** or **select * from tablename** i am getting this error message

```
mysql> desc staff;
ERROR 1286 (42000): Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'
```

and in **show engines** i can't see innodb in the list!!
also i tried to delete the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1, i got another message

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'DBNAME.TableName' doesn't exist
```

I know that i was supposed to mysqldump and restore, but this is what i have done :( , anybody has an idea of how to delete the ibdata1 file and keep innodb engine enabled?
Thanks

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/230551/mysql-innodb-innodb-file-per-table-cons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with innodb_file_per_table setting, the ibdata* still stores critical (meta)data about your tables, you should not have destroyed it. I'm affraid your data are lost, except if there is a way to extract them from the idb files and restore them after the ibdata* file has been rebuilt.

> All the metadata still resides in ibdata1 and there is absolutely no way around that. Redo logs and MVCC data also still live with ibdata1.

Answer (score 0):

Stop mysql, delete innodb log files , start mysql

Comment: i did this already, and mentioned that in my question, in this case i got ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'DBNAME.TableName' doesn't exist