# mysql performance tuning, windows server 2008 R2

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2, mysql5

is there a script/program that I can run for mysql server 5.5 running on windows server 2008 to help optimize the server performance?

the system specs:
2 es5620 @ 2.40 ghz processers (4 cores each)
24 g/b ram x64
server 2008 R2
15k hdd x4 configured using raid 10 (data)
15k hdd x2 configured using raid 1 (system)

any help on maxing performance is appreciated!
founds lot for linux, but not much for windows server 08 r2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using MySQL 5.5.9, 5.5.11 in production Linux environments, here are my observations for using the [InnoDB Buffer Pool](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-do-you-tune-mysql-for-a-heavy-innodb-workload/1185#1185), [handling BLOBs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2273/mysql-gives-out-of-memory-error-when-inserting-a-large-file-where-is-this-file/2300#2300), [Setting Caches](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194), [Diskspace Usage](https://serverfault.com/questions/155455/how-do-myisam-and-innodb-utilize-hd-space/246111#246111) and other [assorted rantings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174396/innodb-performance-tweaks/5348378#5348378) . It applies just as much in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl. But that depends on perl being installed.. otherwise you will have to read the code and try the parameters and mysql commands on the mysql cli